# how to use env.variable in "Editable Email Notification" at Default Content

Tags: jenkins

I have a project that should at the end send an email with a file.
During the build i have the following env.variable:

```
$TARGET_INDEX=/.../.../.../index.html
```

In the "Editable Email Notification" i have configured:

```
Content Type - HTML
Default Content - ${FILE,path="${TARGET_INDEX}"}
```

But at the end of the build I got the below trace:

```
+ TARGET_INDEX=/.../.../.../index.html
[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties file path 'tmp_default.properties'
[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
No emails were triggered.
```

I can't understand why no email was triggered!?

Any clue? Do you have another approach to send email with HTML as content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editable Email Notification has an Attachment section and it use Ant script.when you require an email trigger at the end of your build including file as an attachment then it will help full for you to know  Ant script work mainly on relative addressing rather than absolute addressing. so content in attachment pattern should be some thing like this

`**/foldername/*.txt`

(anyextension)

Note:make sure the floder exists in your job workspace and your index.html is placed in that folder.

Hope this helps to some extent

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the Triggers section, which will be hidden by default.
You need to click the "Advanced Settings" button to show this section.